# how to make div overlap another CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a sort of dropdown menu using list, but the list only shows partially, part of it is hidden by other divs. How can I make it overlap them??

HTML

```
<div id="mph">
    <button type="button" class="btn1"><img src="images\menu.png"/></button>
    <div id="mph1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="plus.html">Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="costumers.html">Costumers</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#mph1{
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying it's ```z-index``` property?  Also, the typo in the example is not in the real code right? (the missing end of the image tag)

Comment: I've just tried that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fz-index):

```
ul{
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
}
```

Note: A element **must** have an absolute or fixed position for z-index to work!

Comment: Can you post your relevant css and html, along with any js you use? or a demo page with the full coding would be helpful

Comment: js:
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#mph1").hide();
  $("button.btn1").click(function() {
    $("#mph1").show(function(){
 $("button.btn1").hide()}
 );
  });

});

Comment: can you post the html and css for the div that is covering it

Comment: I want it to go over a owl carousel slider http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Comment: Try upping the z-index, to a very high value(999999999)